# MySQL SUM and WHERE gives just single result

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have problem when i use WHERE and COUNT together. I have 3 tables: T1 and T2 and in T3 t1.id and t2.id.

I need to print all result with specific CITY name from T1 and count how many employees are work on that project. SO i tried

```
SELECT t1.name, COUNT(t3.idP)
from t3
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.idP = t3.idP
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.idE = t3.idE
WHERE t2.city = 'SOME CITY NAME'
```

Result is just first project name with number of all employees. If i remove COUNT i can see all project in that city, or if i remove WHERE i can see number of employees in each project. But when have both COUNT and WHERE, i get just first project and number of all project's employees.

Comment: 'If you use an aggregate function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mix normal columns (`t1.name`) with aggregate functions (`COUNT(t3.idP)`), you need to use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT t1.name, COUNT(t3.idP)
from t3
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.idP = t3.idP
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.idE = t3.idE
WHERE t2.city = 'SOME CITY NAME'
GROUP BY t1.name
```

Comment: Thank you for anwsering, but i think that i tried something like this.. Now i try again and get some error : 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(t3.idE) from t3.idE)
from t3
INNER JOIN t2 ON proje' at line 1

Comment: Because is on my language.. so this way is better. It's okey now.. I read about this and about GROUP BY.. Everything is work fine.

Comment: For the future, it is always best to show the actual query (regardless of the language  used in table/column names).

Comment: Okey, I'll keep that in mind. I never ask before, because you can find everything on google.. But... :)